# Extracting JSon data from AJAX call in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
{"appResponse":{"status":"Success","description":"","responseData":{"maintenanceWindows":[{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027438,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":8400,"effectiveDate":1522209600000,"expiryDate":1543554000000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1510179232000,"rowLastUpdated":1510179232000},{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027439,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":8400,"effectiveDate":1522209600000,"expiryDate":1543554000000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1510179232000,"rowLastUpdated":1510179232000},{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027440,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":8400,"effectiveDate":1522209600000,"expiryDate":1543554000000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1510179232000,"rowLastUpdated":1510179232000},{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027649,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":1800,"effectiveDate":1511326800000,"expiryDate":1511499600000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1511169722000,"rowLastUpdated":1511169722000},{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027638,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":12600,"effectiveDate":1511067600000,"expiryDate":1551416400000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1510827006000,"rowLastUpdated":1510827006000},{"maintenanceScheduleId":1027661,"sumInfoId":5,"startTime":null,"duration":9000,"effectiveDate":1513659600000,"expiryDate":1513832400000,"timeZone":null,"rowCreated":1511263590000,"rowLastUpdated":1511263590000}]}}}
```

I want extract maintenanceWindows list such as startTime,endTime etc  in angularJS.

Comment: Ok. Please do extract the data. Come back when you have more specific question or problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stringify = '{
    "appResponse": {
        "status": "Success",
        "description": "",
        "responseData": {
            "maintenanceWindows": [{
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027438,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 8400,
                "effectiveDate": 1522209600000,
                "expiryDate": 1543554000000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1510179232000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1510179232000
            }, {
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027439,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 8400,
                "effectiveDate": 1522209600000,
                "expiryDate": 1543554000000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1510179232000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1510179232000
            }, {
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027440,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 8400,
                "effectiveDate": 1522209600000,
                "expiryDate": 1543554000000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1510179232000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1510179232000
            }, {
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027649,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 1800,
                "effectiveDate": 1511326800000,
                "expiryDate": 1511499600000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1511169722000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1511169722000
            }, {
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027638,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 12600,
                "effectiveDate": 1511067600000,
                "expiryDate": 1551416400000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1510827006000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1510827006000
            }, {
                "maintenanceScheduleId": 1027661,
                "sumInfoId": 5,
                "startTime": null,
                "duration": 9000,
                "effectiveDate": 1513659600000,
                "expiryDate": 1513832400000,
                "timeZone": null,
                "rowCreated": 1511263590000,
                "rowLastUpdated": 1511263590000
            }]
        }
    }
}'

var obj = JSON.parse(stringify);
console.log(obj.appResponse.responseData.maintenanceWindows[0].startTime);
```

you can get all `startTime` using loop, `obj.appResponse.responseData.maintenanceWindows`

Comment: Getting error in(angular.min.js:123 SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)) var obj = JSON.parse(stringify);

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize this string to object via [angular.fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson)

Answer (score 0):

`res` is your response from ajax

```
const myJson = res.JSON().appResponse;
const maintenanceWindows = myJson.responseData.maintenanceWindows
```

Now you can get your data using maintenanceWindows